# Every closed interval in $R^1$ is closed set (check logic)

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I want to prove, that every closed interval in $\mathbb{R}^1$ is closed set.

Can I use the argument, that there are uncountably many points in $\mathbb{R}^1$ and if we will take arbitrary point $x$,that belongs to a closed interval,and take arbitrary neighbourhood around this  point, we will always find a point, that belongs to the interval. It means, that our point is a limit point. Because point is arbitrary and neighbourhood as well it means, that this set is closed.

Comment: Something is very dodgy there. What's your definition of closed set?

Comment: I would consider the complement, and show that every element of the complement has an open neighborhood contained within the complement, hence the complement is open, implying the interval is closed.

Comment: @Bowditch Closed set is the set, that contains all it limit points.I edited post a bit

Comment: No. Backwards. You should prove that a limit point of the interval belongs to the interval. So starting with a point that belongs to the interval is not the right route.

Comment: With your logic, take a point from an open interval, then there are uncountably many points around that point. So, an open interval becomes closed (which is not true of course).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're supposed to prove that any limit point of $I$ is within $I$, but what you do in your proof is to a-priori assume that $x\in I$ and then prove that $x$ is a limit point of $I$. Actually what you're proving is that $I$ is dense in itself, note how your proof also works for open intervals.

Besides your proof is broken as the uncountability of a $\mathbb R$ doesn't imply that at all. First it doesn't say anything about $I$ being uncountable, and even if it were one can construct such sets that are not dense in itself. Note that a closed interval as opposed to an open does not need to have infinite elements: the closed interval $[0,0]$ only contains $0$.

What you instead should have done is to start with a limit point $x$ of $I=[a,b]$. Which in turn mean that every neighborhood $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ of $x$ intersects $I$, that there is a point $c\in I$ such that $|x-c|<\epsilon$. Now $a\le c\le b$ which means that $x<b+\epsilon$ and $x>a-\epsilon$. This has to be true for any $\epsilon>0$ which means that $a\le x\le b$ (for assume for example that $x<a$ then we would have $a-x>0$ and the assumption $x>a-\epsilon$ would fail if $\epsilon = (a-x)/2$ since then $a-\epsilon = a-a/2+x/2 = a/2+x/2 < x$).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand from your claim, you prove that every member of a closed interval is a limit point of the interval. You need to prove that every limit point of a closed interval is a point of the interval, instead.

Pick any closed interval $[a,b]$. Pick any $x$ that is not a member of $[a,b]$, hence $x < a$ or $b < x$. Assume that $x$ is a limit point of $[a,b]$, hence it is not closed. Without loss of generality, pick $b < x$. Then in the segment $(b,x)$ there are no points of $[a,b]$, contradicting $x$ being a limit point. Then there is no point which is not a member of the closed interval and is a limit point of the interval in the same time.

With your proof and this, additionally it becomes apparent that $[a,b]$ is a perfect set.

Comment: The situation $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and $x=1.1$ fits your assumptions, but $(0.1,2.1)\cap[0,1]\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: $(0.1,2.1) \cap [0,1] = (0.1,1] $ and it is not a closed interval?

Comment: Your claim is that the segment $(x-b,x+b)$ is disjoint from $[a,b]$, which is not always the case.

Comment: Ok, you are right. What I meant is $(b,2x-b) $ actually.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how your argument is in any way a proof of the original claim. There are two major problems with it:

1. You did not tell us what definition of closed set you are using.
2. You did not structure the argument, so it is impossible to follow.

---

A *good* argument would look something like this:

> Claim: Every closed interval $I$ is a closed set.
>
> Proof: Let $I$ be a closed interval.
>   By definition, a set $A$ is closed if and only if ___________.  Therefore, we want to prove that ______________ is true for $I$. ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
>   Therefore, we have shown that ________________ is true for $I$. We conclude that $I$ is closed.
>
> Because $I$ was an arbitrary closed interval, we know that every closed interval is a closed set.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have done a good job of explaining why your reasoning needs some work, I'll only discuss your original problem here.

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. There are two common definitions of a closed set you should be familiar with:

> 1. The set $A$ contains all of its limit points. Symbolically, this means that $A=\bar{A}$.
> 2. The complement, $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$, is open.

We will prove that $A=[a,b]$ for any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ where $a<b$ is closed (in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$) using both definitions. I encourage you to try and spot the similarities between these two arguments.

1. First, suppose that $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of $A$ such that $x\notin A$. This means that for any $\epsilon>0$, the set $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ contains points of $A$. If $x<a$, we consider any $\epsilon < \frac{a-x}{2}$. However, this implies that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ does *not* contain any points of $A$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $x$ cannot be a limit point of $A$, so $x\in A$. By definition, this means $A$ is closed. (You should prove the case when $x>b$ yourself).
2. Consider the complement of $A$, which we denote $B:=(-\infty, a)\cup(b,\infty)$. Given any $x\in B$, we can find some open ball $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ that is entirely contained within $B$ (you should prove this statement). By definition, this implies that $B$ is open, and therefore $A$ is closed also by definition.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard definition of closed set,"the complement of an open set is called  $closed$".Any closed interval $[a,b]$ is the complement of the union of two open sets  $(-\infty,a)$ and $(b,\infty)$(union of open sets is open).

Comment: Precisely it is @Subhajit Saha. But you need to modify your answer according to what OP asked. Clearly here OP wanted to prove this fact using equivalent definition of closed set  i.e. derived set definition rather than the topological definition you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently, a subset A of a metric space X is closed if and only if the limit of every convergent sequence in A is in A.

Let $[a,b]$ be a closed interval. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in A so that $x_n$ $\rightarrow x$ where x $\notin A$.

Consider the two cases

$x<a$ and $x>b$ and try to get a contradiction in both cases by choosing a suitable $\epsilon>0$ in either case.